# How to add the fields when join keyword in used in laravel querybuilder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to add sellamount and buyamount. I have tried the following code snippet but its shows error. Can anyone help please?

```
DB::table('tbl_buyer')
->select('buyer','tbl_seller.seller','buyamount','tbl_seller.sellamount',
'buyamount + sellamount')
->join('tbl_seller','tbl_seller.seller','=','tbl_buyer.buyer')
->get();
```

Comment: explain with some sample data please

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: tbl_buyer
buyer buyamount
1 10
2 20


tbl_seller
seller sellamount
1 10
2 20

result
buyer buyamount sellamount buyamount+sellamount
1 10 10  20
2 20 20  30

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buyamount + sellamount' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
DB::table('tbl_buyer')
->select('buyer','tbl_seller.seller','buyamount','tbl_seller.sellamount','(buyamount + tbl_seller.sellamount) as total')
->join('tbl_seller','tbl_seller.seller','=','tbl_buyer.buyer')
->get();
```

Comment: Did not work . SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buyamount + tbl_seller.sellamount' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for helping.
This works for me.

```
DB::table('tbl_buyer')
->select(\DB::raw('buyer,tbl_seller.seller,buyamount,tbl_seller.sellamount, buyamount + tbl_seller.sellamount as total '))
->join('tbl_seller','tbl_seller.seller','=','tbl_buyer.buyer')
->orderBy('total','Desc')
->limit(5)
->get();
```